# Do Google Cloud IP's can be used by normally users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

After few days of huge attacks what was come from China most of them, today i start to get a lot of hits from Google Cloud IP's ( they don't even follow robots.txt file ) can i know if this is Google Bots Crawler or is people using Google Cloud IP's to crawler the websites? If i block them can affect my google ranking?

Ips list:

```
August 3, 2017, 12:00 am - 107.178.194.117 - 6
August 3, 2017, 12:00 am - 107.178.194.96 - 6
August 3, 2017, 12:00 am - 107.178.194.115 - 6
August 3, 2017, 12:00 am - 107.178.194.115 - 5
August 3, 2017, 12:00 am - 107.178.194.96 - 5
August 3, 2017, 12:00 am - 107.178.194.96 - 4
August 3, 2017, 12:00 am - 107.178.194.113 - 12
August 3, 2017, 12:00 am - 107.178.194.113 - 11
August 3, 2017, 12:00 am - 107.178.194.99 - 4
August 3, 2017, 12:00 am - 107.178.194.127 - 5
August 3, 2017, 12:00 am - 107.178.194.117 - 5
August 3, 2017, 12:00 am - 107.178.194.127 - 4
August 3, 2017, 12:00 am - 107.178.194.115 - 4
August 3, 2017, 12:00 am - 107.178.194.127 - 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting into webmaster tools of google:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools

in the "Crawl" section, you can see exactly what google crawlers doing in your site.

Google crawlers, only follow the paths that you already set in your robots.txt [google link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en). here's an example:

```
#all crawlers
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /
Disallow: /[dont-crawl-this-pad]/

#yahoo 
User-agent: Slurp
Allow: /
User-Agent: msnbot
Disallow: /
```

If you suspect that an ip is scanning the site outside the defined path in robots.txt, You can block it without hesitation, in any way you can know the status of crawlers with webmaster tools, so that your site stays positioned

Hope this info help.